# Simulator won't start, stuck on Verifying "Simulator" after updating my Xcode to 8.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

I have updated my Xcode to 8.2.1 after that am trying to run my code, but the simulator won't start, its stuck on verifying "simulator" taking two more days still it can't run. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: can you attach the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug for Macs that don't support METAL. (For more details: [Xcode 8.2 problem with simulator](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67204))

As a temporary solution, try to restart you project (clean 'Derived Data'). If not resolved, then....

> Use latest Xcode Tool: [Xcode 8.3.2](https://developer.apple.com/download/)

(Completely remove(uninstall) Xcode & supporting files from your system, prior to instal new tool)

Comment: can you add the radar for this bug

Comment: Okay i will try the new version. Thank you @krunal.

Answer (score 0):

I have just quit the running existed project in Xcode(8.2.1) and then create a new project and tried to run the simulator it works!!